# how to colour geom_hline() using an aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

geom_hline seems to be ignoring aesthetics, am I missing something or is this a bug?

```
df <- data.frame(
    "x"=rep(c(1,2,3),2),
    "y"=rep(c(1,2,3),2),
    "g"=rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),each=3)
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5,aes(colour=g)) +
    facet_wrap(~g)
```

This returns as plot with no colour guide and all black lines

[image]

I get the same thing with e.g. `linetype=g`

setting colour outside an aesthetic works e.g. 
`geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5,colour="red") +`

---

sesionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.8.0    bindrcpp_0.2.2  rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.2.0      forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1  
 [7] dplyr_0.7.6     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.0.0  
[13] tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19       lubridate_1.7.4    lattice_0.20-35    assertthat_0.2.0   rprojroot_1.3-2   
 [6] digest_0.6.17      utf8_1.1.4         mime_0.6           R6_2.3.0           cellranger_1.1.0  
[11] plyr_1.8.4         backports_1.1.2    evaluate_0.11      httr_1.3.1         pillar_1.3.0      
[16] rlang_0.2.2        lazyeval_0.2.1     curl_3.2           readxl_1.1.0       rstudioapi_0.8    
[21] data.table_1.11.8  rmarkdown_1.10     labeling_0.3       selectr_0.4-1      htmlwidgets_1.3   
[26] munsell_0.5.0      shiny_1.1.0        broom_0.5.0        compiler_3.4.4     httpuv_1.4.5      
[31] modelr_0.1.2       pkgconfig_2.0.2    base64enc_0.1-3    htmltools_0.3.6    tidyselect_0.2.4  
[36] fansi_0.4.0        viridisLite_0.3.0  crayon_1.3.4       withr_2.1.2        later_0.7.5       
[41] grid_3.4.4         nlme_3.1-137       jsonlite_1.5       xtable_1.8-3       gtable_0.2.0      
[46] magrittr_1.5       scales_1.0.0       cli_1.0.1          stringi_1.2.4      promises_1.0.1    
[51] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.4.4        Cairo_1.5-9        glue_1.3.0         hms_0.4.2         
[56] crosstalk_1.0.0    yaml_2.2.0         colorspace_1.3-2   knitr_1.20         bindr_0.1.1       
[61] haven_1.1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `yintercept` also has to be inside `aes` for the `colour` mapping to work.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1.5, colour=g)) +
  facet_wrap(~g)
```

[image]

I don't know why `geom_hline` works this way. To be consistent with other ggplot geoms, it seems like `yintercept` should be independent of other aesthetics. For example, the `colour` aesthetic works as expected in this case:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(y=1, aes(colour=g)) +
  facet_wrap(~g)
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Anonymouscoward for pointing me to the help for `geom_abline/vline/hline`, which explains that these geoms do not recognize `x` and `y` aesthetics:

> Unlike most other geoms, these geoms do not inherit aesthetics from the plot default, because they do not understand x and y aesthetics which are commonly set in the plot.

See the help for additional details.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 I couldn't find a reason for this so I opened an issue on the ggplot2 github repo: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2945

Comment: Within `?geom_abline` see the `Details` section. It seems like it's one or the other, not one in and one out of `aes`, since it sounds like how it creates the line is unique.

Comment: The help for the argument `yintercept` in `?geom_abline` states: "Parameters that control the position of the line. If these are set, `data`, `mapping` and `show.legend` are overridden." Which is exactly what happens in OP's example.

Comment: `geom_h/v/abline` will now throw a warning when the mappings are going to be overwritten. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2950 , and the behaviour of overwriting user supplied data is being considered see:
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3090